# QGIS categorized styling: show number of objects for a categroy

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

When I have a vector layer with several objects and apply a categorized styling to the layer, ArcGIS Shows me the number ob objects that fall into each category. The following image is from QGIS but in ArcGIS it looks pretty much the same. In ArcGIS next to the legend is for each row a number with objects that fall into the category.

[image]

Is there a similar option in QGIS I'm not seeing? Is there an easy way to query the numbers?

Comment: Having the categorization count show in this panel would be a great suggestion for a feature request on the QGIS GitHub:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Feature+Request&template=feature_request.md&title=

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once your classes are applied, you can activate

```
<layer context menu> | Show feature count
```

in the main *Layer* panel to see the feature count for each class:

[image]